# year 10 factorial question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

I would like to know the number of zeros occuring in the factorial of 2016? (2016!)
I have read some ways but i don't understand it.

Comment: Number of trailing zeros or the total number of them? Because the second one is way harder.

Comment: According to the PARI/GP program ? q=0;x=digits(2016!);for(j=1,length(x),if(x[j]==0,q=q+1));print(q)
1006
? , $2016!$ contains $1006$ zeros. The number of trailing zeros is $502$.

Comment: total number. No wonder...the one i searched about were the solutions to the trailing zeros

Comment: The easiest way to find the number of trailing zeros : Divide $2016$ repeatedly by $5$ ignoring the remainder until you arrive at $0$ and add all occuring numbers (except $2016$, of course). You get the sequence $403,80,16,3,0$ , which sums up to $502$.

Comment: But for the total number of zeros, there is probably no shortcut.

Comment: @Peter, what is that process called? That's not something I've ever seen before and I'm interested in knowing how/why it works...

Comment: The idea is quite simple : You have to count how many numbers from $1$ to $n$ are divisble by $5$, by $5^2$ , by $5^3$ and so on until we reach a power of $5$ greater than $n$ (here, the number is $0$). There are $n_1=trunc(n/5)$ numbers from $1$ to $n$ divisble by $5$, so we start with $n_1=trunc(n/5)$. $n_2=trunc(n_1/5)$ of these numbers are divisble by $5^2$, the exponent in $5^m$ will increase by $n_2$ because we already covered exponent $1$ with $n_1$. You can continue until $n_k=0$ and the sum of the $n_i$'s is the desired number.

Comment: I do not know a name for this process.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions . Under "Factors of factorials" you find an explicit formula of the exponent of $p^s$ in the prime factorization of $n!$. If you choose $p=5$, you get the number of trailing zeros of $n!$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's quite interesting.

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the number of trailing zeros you need to determine how many times $10$ divides $2016!$.  In order for a factor of 10 to be present you need a (prime) factor of $2$ and a (prime) factor of $5$.  So think about how many number are divisible from $1, 2, 3, ..., 2016$ are divisible by $5$?  There are $\lfloor \frac{2016}{5}\rfloor$ of them.  But this is not all.  Some numbers are divisible by 5 twice (i.e. multiples of 25).  How many multiples of 25 are there (1 extra prime factor for each multiple)?  There are $\lfloor \frac{2016}{25}\rfloor$ of them.  Some of those numbers are also divisible by 5 three times (i.e. multiples of 125).  Find the number of those in the same way.  Follow this procedure until $5^{k} > 2016$.  Add up all those values and you have the number of times $5$ appears as a factor.  You can similarly count how many times $2$ occurs, but all you need to be certain of is that $2$ occurs at least as many times as $5$ does (I'll leave this to you to determine, not hard).

Comment: There may be a nicer "number theory" way to do this.  This is a "combinatorial" way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to the problem would be as follows:

- $5^1$: 2016÷5 = 403.2, so I have 403 factors of 5
- $5^2$: 2016÷25 = 80.64, so I have 80 factors of 25
- $5^3$: 2016÷125 = 16.128, so I have 16 factors of 125
- $5^4$: 2016÷625 = 3.22, so I have 3 factors of 625
- $5^5$: 2016÷3125 < 1, so I stop here.

In total, I now have 403+80+16+3 = **502** **trailing zeroes.**